# How can I check if the user has any of listed permissions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I check if the user has any of listed permissions? It's a big list, so I didn't want to use:

```
if (interaction.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS') || interaction.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS') || ...)
```

I tried using array, but it only works if the user has all those permissions.

```
if (interaction.member.permissions.has(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS', ...]))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `if ([permission1, permission2, ...].some(permission => interaction.member.permissions.has(permission)))`?

Comment: Thank you so much! @HereticMonkey